# ElasticSearch: Aggregations for the count of documents that has empty nested array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-8

**Question**- I want a count of documents where the nested array MATCHES is empty like "MATCHES": [ ].
My **document structure** looks like this(shows two records for simplicity) -

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "ef0a2c44179a513476b080cc2a585d95",
      "_source": {
        "DIVISION_NUMBER": 44,
        "MATCHES": [
          {
            "MATCH_STATUS": "APPROVED",
            "UPDATED_ON": 1599171303000
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "ef0a2c44179a513476b080cc2a585d95",
      "_source": {
        "DIVISION_NUMBER": 44,
        "MATCHES": [ ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Solution tried**- I tried following different ways (workaround) of aggregation (empty-match-agg1,empty-match-agg2 ...) but none of these gave correct results. Please help!

```
 "aggs": {
    "sku": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "MATCHES"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "empty-match-agg1": {
          "missing": {
            "field": "MATCHES"
          }
        },
        "empty-match-agg2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "MATCHES",
            "missing": "N/A"
          }
        },
        "empty-match-agg3": {
          "sum": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "source": "params['_source'].MATCHES"
            }
          }
        },
        "empty-match-agg4": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                  },
                  "path": "MATCHES"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "empty-match-agg5": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "MATCHES"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing aggregation does not support nested field for now. There is [open](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9571) issue as of now.

To get count of empty matches, you can use a filter aggregation with the nested query wrapped into the must_not clause of the bool query.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "missing_matches_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "nested": {
              "query": {
                "match_all": {}
              },
              "path": "MATCHES"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the same as what I tried with "empty-match-agg4" in my solutions. it's not giving me the correct results.

Comment: @KunwarShukla I tried with  sample documents in question. Can you add an example where it is failing.

Comment: @KunwarShukla in your solution  empty-match-agg4 is subaggregtaion of "sku". Try it outside of it

Comment: Yes, I figured that too and it worked. Thank you! Hope it helps someone else too. Elastic Search documentation needs correction that this particular feature doesn't work with nested fields.

Comment: @KunwarShukla Please mark as answer if it resolved your issue